# Separating work and personal tabs in firefox

Tags: windows-10, firefox, user-experience

I am using my laptop for working and personal usage. I use usually many tabs for in my work and i keep using them for several days. Everyday in the afternoon when i want to use my laptop for personal stuff, i feel it's annoying to have the working tabs opened.

Thus, is there a way to have like two firefox shortcuts in the desktop where when I open any of them, a group of tabs open?

EDIT

I am looking for a solution that can keep track of the last tabs that were opened in each mode (e.g. working, personal).

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @MendelG windows

Comment: [MySessions – Get this Extension for  Firefox (en-GB)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/my-sessions/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple batch script to start multiple websites in different tabs. Save the following with a `.bat` extension and run it:

```
start https://name_of_website
start https://website
```

Comment: thanks for this, but i am looking for something that can keep track of the last tabs that were opened. in this way, if i open new things and then close the browser, it will reopen the first tabs that i set.

Comment: @Ghanem [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) might be for befitting for this